# Firebase custom auth token with debug set to true not being verbose

Tags: python, firebase

I am trying to get the verbosity level that the Admin Console Simulator gives but using python on a server.  Using the [firebase_token_generator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-python) suggested in the Firebase docs I wrote some tests.

```
from firebase_token_generator import create_token
create_token("<secret>", { "uid": "simplelogin:test" }, 
                         { "debug": True, "simulate": True })
```

Running the token with curl results in the simple "Permission denied" error with no details about which rule failed.

```
$ curl https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com/.json?auth=<token>
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

To make sure that my secret key was correct and I was setting the options in the correct place I generated a token with admin set to true and it was successful.

```
create_token("<secret>", { "uid": "simplelogin:test" }, { "admin": True })
```

Why can't I get the verbosity level that is in the simulator?

Comment: The security rules simulator is a function of the client libraries, but it is not available over the REST API.

Comment: Then can someone explain what the debug option does?

Comment: When using the client library and reading from / writing to Firebase, you'll get console logging that describes which security expressions are passing or failing for debugging purposes.

Comment: So you are saying that the debug option only works from a browser?

Comment: The debug option only works from a client library, whether that client be the JS client (Web or Node.js), ObjC (iOS or OS-X), or Java (Android or JVM).

Comment: I.e. it works everywhere except the REST API. @RobDiMarco this should be an answer, since it is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using a Firebase client library in order to receive verbose security rule logging when using a token with the `debug` flag set - whether that client be the JS client (Web or Node.js), ObjC (iOS or OS-X), or Java (Android or JVM). Alas, the REST API is not supported.

Comment: It would also be awesome to know the reason why the REST API is not supported

Comment: Why is it not supported?

Comment: @brisebom I don't have a concrete answer here, but the debug logging doesn't translate as well to the REST API because we don't have the same built-in logging mechanism. The debugging could be placed in the data payload, but then it might be confused with the actual *data* in your Firebase, and you would have to write code to separate the two. Alternatively, it could be written back in a bunch of separate HTTP response headers, but you might need special code to handle that too. In general, we're highly optimized for use of the client libraries as they provide the real-time / offline benefits.